# How to implement a form without using form element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have been trying to implement a form without using the form element but no success yet. I have two .php files, **file1.php** and **file2.php**

I tried to implement it using the **onclick** of a button in **file1.php**, but I can't seem to understand how it works:

```
    function submitData(){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "file2.php";
    var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
    http.open("POST", url, true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send(params);
}
```

The function works well, upon the button click it returns the the whole text of **file2.php**. But this is not what I am trying to achieve. I want this button click to get me to **file2.php** and from there I can get the parameters and use them further. When I use the form eleement upon clicking the submit button it will get me to **file2.php** but the above code does not seem to do that. I know I am missing something very obvious here :/ ?

Comment: First of all, why not just use a form? But have you tried AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

> I want this button click to get me to file2.php

I don't know if I undestand you well, but you have to know that XMLHttpRequest() is used to AJAX connections.

AJAX means: **Asynchronous** JavaScript and XML

**Asynchronous** menas, that you will be NOT redirected to this file. You will stay in the file file1.php, and at this time the server will run file2.php and give you an answer. 
XMLHttpRequest is not used for show you another file. This is useful, when you want to get an answer from a PHP file, without leaving a current page.

Answer (score 0):

Try some jquery like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#yourBtnId').click(function(){
    //Define all of your form data from input fields, something like:
    var formData = {
      'name' : $('input[name=inputName]').val(),
      //put more here similar to above
    };

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST', //or get whatever
        url : 'urltophpfilewhereyouprocesspost',
        data : formData,
        dataType : 'json', //or whatever
        encode : true
    })

        .done(function(data){
            //do whatever you want 
        });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});